# A list of customized checkboxes only first one work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a list of customized checkboxes but after applying the style only the first checkbox respond to the button click :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    .style-input {
  display: none;
}

.style-input + label:after {
  content: "";
}

.style-input:checked + label:after {
  content: "";
}
    </style>

<body>
    <div>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class='style-input' />
        <label for="checkbox"></label>
    </div>

    <div >
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class='style-input' />
        <label for="checkbox"></label>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

`id`s must be unique for each element. Thus, you need to give both your checkboxes a unique `id`. If you change the `id` however, you must also change the `for` attribute on the `label` to match the `id` of the respective checkbox.

Also, as a side note, I recommend you use the escaped unicode to represent your characters:

- `\1F91C` for the empty box
- `\1F44D` for the thumbs-up emoji

For future reference, you can convert characters yourself by using [this lookup](https://unicodelookup.com/#%F0%9F%91%8D/1) and then using the HEX value and replace the `0x` with a `\`

See working example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .style-input {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .style-input+label:after {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  
  .style-input+label:after {
    content: "\1F91C";
  }
  
  .style-input:checked+label:after {
    content: "\1F44D";
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div>
    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class='style-input' />
    <label for="checkbox1"></label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" class='style-input' />
    <label for="checkbox2"></label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain to the OP why escaping the emoji characters is better than using the characters themselves?

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you changed the id for the second item :

```
<html>
<style>
    .style-input {
  display: none;
}

.style-input + label:after {
  content: "";
}

.style-input:checked + label:after {
  content: "";
}
    </style>

<body>
    <div>
        <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class='style-input' />
        <label for="checkbox"></label>
    </div>

    <div >
        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" class='style-input' />
        <label for="checkbox2"></label>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The id for each checkbox needs to be unique, then it will function as expected.